# Pagination and Sorting not working

Tags: magento-1.8, frontend, sorting, pagination

For my custom module I have get product by manufacturer. For template I have copied `list.phtml`.

On the template file pagination appears but it shows all product instead of selected limit per page. Sorting is not working too.

How can I make it work??

It is my block file:

```
protected function _getProductCollection() 
{
    if (is_null($this->_productCollection)) {
        $layer = $this->getLayer();
        $brand_id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
        $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
        $collection->addFieldToFilter(array(
            array('attribute' => 'manufacturer', 'eq' => $brand_id)
        ));
    }

    return $collection;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use below snippet to add pagination and sorting on your custom collection. For every custom collection listing you have to create custom toolbar pager as well.

```
    $itemsLimit         =   $_GET["limit"] ? $_GET["limit"] : Mage::getStoreConfig('catalog/frontend/grid_per_page');   //Set items to show per page
    $currPage               =   $_GET["p"] ? $_GET["p"] : 1;                //Set current page      
   /*   Set Pagination for Custom Loaded Collection */                              
    $toolbar = Mage::getBlockSingleton('catalog/product_list')->getToolbarBlock();
    $toolbar->setCollection($_productCollection);

    /*  Set Pager   */
    $pager = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('page/html_pager', 'custom.pager');
    $pager->setAvailableLimit(array($itemsLimit=>$itemsLimit));
    $pager->setCollection($_productCollection);
    $toolbar->setChild('product_list_toolbar_pager', $pager);
    $toolbar->setData('_current_limit', $itemsLimit);
```

After this, replace

```
$this->getToolbarHtml(); by $toolbar->toHtml();
```

to display bottom pager and top sorting toolbar.

For sorting order, do this before collection load:

```
$_productCollection->addAttributeToSort($_GET["order"], $_GET["dir"]');
```

I hope this resolves your problem.

Comment: also you can add

$_productCollection->setPageSize($itemsLimit)
           ->setCurPage($currPage);

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the situation in your case, but it might help someone else who is having this problem.  I had this problem while testing  custom changes in `getProductCollection()`.

I was able to fix it by removing logging code I had added that noted the count of the returned collection. I believe that anything that interrogates the Collection load results in the `getProductCollection()` method will force the collection to actually load its products prematurely and will prevent downstream modifications to the collection ordering and result limitation from being applied for the paging controls.

Comment: To still be able to log the collection count without loading the collection items, use `$collection->getSize()`. It will perform a separate `SELECT COUNT(*)` with current collection filters.

Comment: Thanks @Jan Papenbrock.  That is handy.  The larger point I was trying to make though remains.  If you cause the collection to load, it will interfere with paging and sorting which are applied to the collection later if it has not been loaded.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use following filters too:

```
    ->addAttributeToSort($_GET['order'],$_GET['dir'] )
    ->setPageSize($limit)
    ->setCurPage($_GET['p'])
```

So your complete code becomes:

```
    protected function _getProductCollection() 
    {
        if (is_null($this->_productCollection)) 
        {
            $layer = $this->getLayer();
            $brand_id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
            $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
            $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
            $collection->addFieldToFilter(array(array('attribute'=>'manufacturer','eq'=>$brand_id),
    ))
$collection->addAttributeToSort($_GET['order'],$_GET['dir'] );
    $collection->setPageSize($_GET['limit']);
    $collection->setCurPage($_GET['p']);



        }

        return $collection;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to override the `_prepareLayout()` and set the data as below snap.

```
protected function _prepareLayout()
{
    parent::_prepareLayout();
    $pager = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('page/html_pager')->setCollection($this->getDatasets());
    $this->setChild('pager', $pager);
    $this->getDatasets()->load();
    return $this;
}
```

let me know if you have any query.

Comment: it still not working. after adding this it displays white screen.

Comment: it will not just like copy and paste buddy

Answer (score 0):

Go to Manage Category Section and set is Anchor Option to "Yes".